# Node Unhandled Promise Rejection

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda

I don't know why I'm getting unhandled promise rejection warning for the following:

```
if (cacheDb === null) {
    cacheDb = await MongoClient.connect(mongoUri)
        .then(client => client.db(mongoDb)
        .catch(err => throw new Error(err))
}
```

I tried wrapping it in try&catch too.

```
if (cacheDb === null) {
    try {
        cacheDb = await MongoClient.connect(mongoUri)
        cacheDb = cacheDb.db(mongoDb)
    } catch (err) {
        throw err
    }
}
```

The main function is an async aws lambda handler with node v8.10.0.

Comment: You realize that the try catch does nothing right? You're catching the error then immediately rethrowing.

Comment: I'm doing some logging then throwing the error in actual code. If I misunderstand your point, could you explain more?

Comment: you are handling with catch and then throwing back the same exception which for this promise remains unhandled. Unhandled because there is no more promise above it for it to bubble and seek it's `catch`

Comment: I see. Thank you for explaining it for me. How would I throw the err back to aws lambda?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if (cacheDb === null) {
    try {
        cacheDb = await MongoClient.connect(mongoUri)
        cacheDb = cacheDb.db(mongoDb)
    } catch (err) {
        throw new Error(err);
    }
}
```